# How to get location from Google Place API JSON (android)

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I have type below to get Location array to get the latitude, but it can not work.
Is it any mistake in my code? And i can get the result, but i cannot get geometry.

```
 JSONTokener jsonParser = new JSONTokener(strResult);  
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResult);

 JSONArray routeObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

routeObject.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("geometry").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("location").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("lat")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way:

The google maps url:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+fullAddress;

And I read it:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject point = response.getJSONArray("Placemark").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("Point");

            lat = point.getJSONArray("coordinates").getString(1);
            lng = point.getJSONArray("coordinates").getString(0);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I never used `google-places-api`, but I just tried something. I just toke the example file from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ **place-search-response** and copied it to a file as input. (edit: I am using http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ to decode)

My code to decode the JsonFile looks like that and gives you the `latitude` you are looking for:

```
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject obj = (JsonObject)parser.parse(new FileReader(path));

        for(Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println(key);

            if(key.trim().equals("results".trim())) {
                for(JsonElement ele2 : entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray()) {
                    System.out.println(ele2.getAsJsonObject().get("geometry").getAsJsonObject().get("location").getAsJsonObject().get("lat"));
                }
            }
        }
```